# Вывод общей суммы товара по его количеству Woocommerce

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

Есть такой код:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_total_product_price', 31 );
function woocommerce_total_product_price() {
global $woocommerce, $product;
echo sprintf('<div id="product_total_price" style="margin-bottom:20px;">%s %s</div>',__('Product Total:','woocommerce'),'<span class="price1">'.$product->get_price().'</span>');
?>
    <script>
        jQuery(function($){
            var price1 = <?php echo $product->get_price(); ?>,
                currency = '<?php echo get_woocommerce_currency_symbol(); ?>';

            $('[name=quantity]').change(function(){
                if (!(this.value < 1)) {

                    var product_total = parseFloat(price1 * this.value);

                    $('#product_total_price .price1').html( currency + product_total.toFixed(2));

                }
            });
        });
    </script>
<?php
}
?>
```

Данный код выводит общую сумму по количеству товара, прямо в каталог товаров для каждого из них. Но есть проблема. При выборе количества товара цена меняется у всех товаров на странице, а не только у того, для которого выбрали количества. Скрин прилагаю. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Добавьте итоговую html-разметку каталога

Comment: Очевидно, что селектор "#product_total_price .price1" одинаков для всех блоков и нужно использовать $(this) с поиском по родителю или сиблингам.

Comment: @zhurof подправьте пожалуйста код, как должно быть.

Comment: @Lemp, да без проблем. Только не зная html-структуры вашего каталога, это будет гадание на кофейной гуще. Хотя-бы ссылку на сайт скиньте

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это вместо вашего кода из вопроса:

```html
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_total_product_price', 31 );
function woocommerce_total_product_price() {
  global $woocommerce, $product;
  $currency = get_woocommerce_currency_symbol();
  $unit_price = $product->get_price();
  echo sprintf('<div style="margin-bottom:20px;">%s %s</div>',__('Product Total:','woocommerce'),'<span class="price1" data-unit-price="'.$unit_price.'">'.$currency.$unit_price.'</span>');
}
?>
```

А это надо поместить в `js`-файл темы

```js
jQuery(function($){    
    $('.archive-products').on('change','[name=quantity]',function(){
      var card = $(this).parents('.product-col'),
          currency = card.find('.woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol').text() || '$',
          unitPrice = card.find('.price1').data('unit-price') || 0;

      if(this.value >= 1) {
          var totalPrice = parseFloat(unitPrice * this.value);
          card.find('.price1').text(currency + totalPrice.toFixed(2));
      }
    });
});
```

Comment: Все работает, спасибо.